# Old values for React state while passing it to a function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

In my simple app I have two (styled-component's) inputs with type of **date**:

```
<DateInput 
  type="date" 
  name="startDate" 
  value={state.startDate} 
  onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e)} 
  required 
/>
<DateInput 
  type="date" 
  name="endDate" 
  value={state.endDate} 
  onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e)} 
  required 
/>
```

Every time I change the date of any of those inputs the function **handleInputChange** is being called:

```
  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    setState({ ...state, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    dataValidation(state);
  };
```

This function updates the state with the new values from date inputs and then I'm running my **dataValidation** function where I'm passing my state to validate the dates (I'm checking if the start date is not greater than the end date).
My problem is that when I pass this state it has older values, for example:

```
Input value: 01.01.2021
State value: 12.31.2019

Input value: 01.02.2021
State value: 01.01.2021

Input value 01.03.2021
State value: 01.02.2021
```

By that, I can't compare my dates. I see that this is some kind of latency for state updates. Can I somehow wait for my **dataValidation** function to run after the state will be updated?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

State is updated asynchronously and the state is constant within a particular render of a react component. To see the updated state, component needs to re-render.

You can fix your problem using one of the following options:

- Use the `useEffect` hook that executes whenever your state is updated and the component has re-rendered. You can call the `dataValidation` function from the `useEffect` hook but then you need to add it in the dependency array.

  ```
  useEffect(() => {
    dataValidation(state);
  }, [state, dataValidation]);
  ```

  *(Make sure you wrap the `dataValidation` function in the `useCallback` hook to avoid running the `useEffect` hook infinitely).*

  Alternatively, you could move the code of the `dataValidation` function inside the `useEffect` hook.

  ```
  useEffect(() => {
    // write your data validation code here
  }, [state]);
  ```
- If you don't want to use the `useEffect` hook, you could change the implementation of the `handleInputChange` function as shown below:

  ```
  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
     // create an object representing the new state
     const newState = { ...state, [e.target.name]: e.target.value };

     // pass the "newState" object to both "setState" and
     // "dataValidation" function
     setState(newState);
     dataValidation(newState);
  };
  ```

Answer (score 0):

From react doc :
The set function only updates the state variable for the next render. If you read the state variable after calling the set function, you will still get the old value that was on the screen before your call.

From my knowledge, you can use this code...

setState(prevValue=> update the value as you wanted to)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).